# How to correct indentation in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, indentation

In Eclipse we can correct indentation by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.

How can I correct indentation (format code) in Android Studio?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Select the code and press

- On Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>
- On MAC: <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

```
File->settings->Keymap and select 'eclipse' from keymap dropdown.
```

By doing this all the shortcuts of eclipse will work in studio also

Answer (score 3):

File->settings->Keymap and select 'eclipse' from keymap dropdown.